# FIND arrays filled ones in php

Tags: php, arrays, find

I have an array:

```
$array = array("1" => "", "2" => "" , "3" => "data1", "4" => "" , "5" => "data2", "6" => "" );
```

It's declared with `for` leaving some empty values.Array can be too long. I want a method to find filled array numbers in PHP.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You mean keys with data in it by filled array or just checking if the array is empty or not ?

Comment: @N.B. array can be too long , i am asking about any function .. I have searched and tried but i didn't got , so i posted .. i am new .. so please help and forgive me .

Comment: @roko to find in which keys array have some value ..

Comment: @HRMNS do you want to know which keys have values??..so what your output must show key or values??

Comment: @roko thnx but now i am not even able to give you a vote up .. it's minus minus , i dont know why srry

Comment: :P no problem, you cannot upvote any answer until a you get specific reputation. But accepting answer is a practise you must follow, this encourages ppl to answer you questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this, will give you all empty array keys

```
  <?php
      $array = array("1" => "", "2" => "" , "3" => "data1", "4" => "" , "5" => "data2", "6" => "" );
      $new = array_filter($array, 'strlen');
      $result = array_diff($array, $new);
       print_r($result);
    ?>
```

If you want to remove the empty value keys
[use array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
    <?php
      $array = array("1" => "", "2" => "" , "3" => "data1", "4" => "" , "5" => "data2", "6" => "" );
      $new = array_filter($array, 'strlen');
      print_r($new);
    ?>
```

Comment: i want the keys , i will use keys to update a column of SQL

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($array as $key=> $value)
{
   if($value != '')
       $newArray[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array("1" => "", "2" => "" , "3" => "data1", "4" => "" , "5" => "data2", "6" => "" );

$array_with_keys = array();


foreach($array as $key=> $value)
{
   if($value != '')
       $array_with_keys[] = $key;
}

print_r($array_with_keys);
```

> Since you want only keys this would return you an array with keys which you can use to update the database using a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop

Comment: @HRMNS this would give you an array with keys only but all of the upvoted answers are correct as well you could use foreach(array as key => value) and use the keys to update your sql.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about what you want, but I think this might help you. Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

```
foreach ($array as $v) {
  if ($v) {
    // this value is not empty
  }
}
```